Understanding analytic irreducibility of homogenous polynomial
I am currently reading a book titled "Numerical semigroups", which can be found here. I have a question regarding a definition provided by the author. To begin, let's define $F=y^n+a_1(x)y^{n-1}+\cdots +a_n(x) \in k[x][y]=k[x, y]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. We also define $h_F(u, x, y) = u^nF(x/u, y/u)$.
Now, considering $\mathbb{P}^2$, the projective 2-space over $k$, with $[0:1:0]$ denoting a point in $\mathbb{P}^2$, the author defines the following:

$F$ has one place at infinity if $h_F$ is analytically irreducible at $[0:1:0]$.

Could someone please explain this definition step by step? I tried to find another source for this definition, but I was unsuccessful. Thank you in advance.

It is not a good idea to post the same question under different titles here and at SE.

@Sasha Sorry for that but I didn't get any answer in the first post. I edit the title in order to make some change so that I get an answer.

This is a basic concept: $h_F$ is the homogenization of $F$ and for the corresponding projective plane curve $X=V(h_F)\subseteq{\mathbb P}^2$, for the local ring of $X$ at the point $P=[0,1,1]$, the definition asks that its completion has no zero divisors.

@F Zaldivar Thank you for your response. Do you happen to have a reference that explains this content?

Zariski-Samuel, Vol. 2  pp. 314--320.

@F Zaldivar, thank you very much, well received.
